# How to "attach" the "i" in a for loop to a vector name in R

Tags: r

I have 40 vectors each containing a bunch of numbers. I want to take the difference between the length of any 2 vectors sequentially like this:

```
length(Vector2) - length(Vector1)
```

then vector3 - vector2 and so on....

how can I construct a for loop so that the "i" attaches to the name of the vector so I can loop through these differences?

like:

```
for (i in 1:10) {

  x[i] <-   length(Vector(i+1)) - length(Vector(i))

}
```

but obviously putting the "i"s inside parentheses is not correct.

thanks,

---

Using the following is almost there:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
   p[i] <- length(get(paste0("KWvectorW", i+1, "$idKeyword"))) - length(get(paste0("KWvectorW", i, "$idKeyword")))
             }
```

which seems to piece the names of the vectors together correctly....but I get the following error:

Error in get(paste0("KWvectorW", i + 1, "$idKeyword")) : 
  object 'KWvectorW2$idKeyword' not found

but the object KWvectorW2$idKeyword definitely exists.

Comment: Better practice would be to put the vectors in a list.

Comment: Do you want to calculate between all combinations of 2 vectors?

Comment: Yes the difference between any 2 vectors. Since there are about 40 vectors I want the diff (in length) between Vector2 - Vector1....and then...Vector3-Vector2....and then.....Vector4-Vector3  etc.

Answer (score 5):

The function `get` is used to reference an object by inputting a character string of the name of the object.

In your example, you would do the following:

```
for (i in 1:10) {

  x[i] <-   length(get(paste0("Vector",i+1))) - length(get(paste0("Vector",i)))

}
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but seriously, like @shujaa mentioned, and as PaulHiemstra demonstrates in his answer, you should never do this.

Comment: This seems almost perfect but see my latest edit...I get an error related to the existence of one of the orignal vectors

Answer (score 4):

I'd put them in a list and use a combination of `sapply`, `length` and `diff`:

```
vec_list = lapply(1:100, function(x) runif(round(runif(1, 1, 100))))
vec_lengths = sapply(vec_list, length)
vec_lengths
  [1]  4 49  7 30 36 35 96  7 38 46 33 25 54 13 68 84 32 56 25 41 41 64 93 81 10
 [26] 91  4 53 34 62 21 12 88 94 71 67 42 39 40 59 10 59 37 19  9 78 46 96 20 68
 [51] 54 54 46 49 12 15 77 91 81 34 21 30 25 56  4 50 35 27 62 49 94 61 59 37 36
 [76] 30 23  2 22 17 16 44 88 41  6 44 62 13 48 57 12 35 84 46 45 10 99 69 50 75
diff(vec_lengths)
 [1]  45 -42  23   6  -1  61 -89  31   8 -13  -8  29 -41  55  16 -52  24 -31  16
[20]   0  23  29 -12 -71  81 -87  49 -19  28 -41  -9  76   6 -23  -4 -25  -3   1
[39]  19 -49  49 -22 -18 -10  69 -32  50 -76  48 -14   0  -8   3 -37   3  62  14
[58] -10 -47 -13   9  -5  31 -52  46 -15  -8  35 -13  45 -33  -2 -22  -1  -6  -7
[77] -21  20  -5  -1  28  44 -47 -35  38  18 -49  35   9 -45  23  49 -38  -1 -35
[96]  89 -30 -19  25
```